# Export geometry to Ansys or other 3D CAD programs?

Tags: export, geometry

I'm a new user of Blender and I would like to know if I can export after-render geometry (in particular I would like to simulate falling spheres in a tube) in order to use it in a different program (like Ansys, Catia, etc.).

Comment: What do you mean by exporting "after-render geometry"?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear; I have to take a certain number of spheres and look at their disposition in a tube of a certain diameter, than using this geometry in Ansys CFX code in order to simulate the path of a fluid inside.

Comment: I do not have Ansys, so I can not tell you what format Ansys can import. However blender can export to many different formats.

Comment: I think Ansys can import a lot of CAD format like: SolidWorks, Catia, .iges, probably also Pro-E.